# How do I make my text input start at the top of the laptop-image screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a 'To-Do List' project that I want to include in my portfolio. The text typed into the box starts at the bottom and keeps putting every additional 'to-do' text under the last one so it isn't legible. I'd like for the text to start at the top of the laptop screen that is on the page. Please click the link and enter any text twice and you will see my error.
https://nicoleirene.github.io/js-exercise-2/
My code is below.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>JS Exercise 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Lets Do This</h1>
      <form>

        <label for="user-input" >Type your to do:</label>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Enter To Do!">

            <button type="submit" id="user-submit">Add To Do!</button> 
        </div> 
      </form>

      <ul id="to-do-list" class="to-do-list">

      </ul>


      <!-- Make sure script is loaded at the bottom-->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var userSubmit = document.querySelector('#user-submit');
var toDoList = document.querySelector('#to-do-list');
function addToDo(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');


    if(userInput.value === ''){
        return false;
    }

    toDoList.innerHTML = '<li><i class="fa fa-window-close close-to-do" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + userInput.value + '</li>' +  toDoList.innerHTML;

    userInput.value = '';
}

function removeToDo(event){
    if(event.target.classList.contains('close-to-do')) {
        var li = event.target.parentElement;
        toDoList.removeChild(li);

    }
}

toDoList.addEventListener('click', removeToDo, false);
userSubmit.addEventListener('click', addToDo, false);
```

**CSS**

> ```
> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
> * {
>   box-sizing: border-box;
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
> }
>
> body{
>   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
>   background-color: #FFF;
>   background-image: url("../images/pixel-open-front.png");
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
>   background-attachment: fixed;
>   background-position: center;
>   color: #000;
> }
> h1{
>   text-align: center;
>   padding:;
>   background-color: blue;
>   color:#FFF;
> }
> label{
>   display: block;
>   margin:right;
>   text-align: center;
>   background-color: red;
>   color:white;
> }
> input{
>   /*display:block;
>   margin:auto;*/
> }
> .wrapper{
>   text-align: center;
> }
> button{
>   color:white;
>   background-color:red;
>   border:none; 
>   padding: 5px;
>   margin-top: 5px;
>
> }
> ul{
>   text-align: center;
>   padding: 300px;
>   list-style: none;
>   color:red;
> }
> .close-to-do{
>   display: inline-block;
>   margin-right: 10px;
> }
> ```

Comment: padding 300px of ul is causing it to display middle of screen , change it to 250px

Comment: I made the ul padding 100 px so it is where I want, thank you so much!

Comment: i made my comment as answer, if it is helpful..please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up differently. Padding may cause problems with different screen sizes. Below I put the laptop as the background for the list.

```js
var userSubmit = document.querySelector('#user-submit');
var toDoList = document.querySelector('#to-do-list');

function addToDo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');


  if (userInput.value === '') {
    return false;
  }

  toDoList.innerHTML = '<li><i class="fa fa-window-close close-to-do" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + userInput.value + '</li>' + toDoList.innerHTML;

  userInput.value = '';
}

function removeToDo(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('close-to-do')) {
    var li = event.target.parentElement;
    toDoList.removeChild(li);

  }
}

toDoList.addEventListener('click', removeToDo, false);
userSubmit.addEventListener('click', addToDo, false);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: ;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: right;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

input {
  /*display:block;
  margin:auto;*/
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px; /* same as top background */
  list-style: none;
  color: red;
}

ul:before {
  content: url(https://nicoleirene.github.io/js-exercise-2/images/pixel-open-front.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px; /* same as padding top */
  left: 80px; 
}

.close-to-do {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<h1>Lets Do This</h1>
<form>
  <label for="user-input">Type your to do:</label>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="user-input" id="user-input" placeholder="Enter To Do!">

    <button type="submit" id="user-submit">Add To Do!</button>
  </div>
</form>
<ul id="to-do-list" class="to-do-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, padding on Ul element is causing it to display at the middle of the screen.

Adjust padding to fix your issue.

For responsive design , please use media queries to display text properly